# How to enable autoscroll to/from source permanently for all new project imports?

Tags: intellij-idea

I like the "Autoscroll to/from source" features. Every time I import a new project, I will always enable them. However, it gets annoying when you have to do that every time for a new import. I googled, but couldn't find out how. How can I enable them permanently?

Comment: I would really like this.  It's very annoying to have to turn these on every single time I run "play idea"...

Comment: @Rodney: I have a semi-workaround now, thanks to gradle. Basically, instead of open/import a new project from intellij, I use the gradle idea plugin to generate *.ipr file. I have a wrapper shell script that will use gradle to make the *.ipr file, as well as a *.iws file that has the autoscroll feature turned on. It is not a perfect solution, but I am OK with it for the time being.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

The auto-scroll settings are Project specific and are stored in the `.idea/workspace.xml` file :

[image]

**[Accessing Default Project Settings and Structure](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/accessing-default-project-settings-and-structure.html)** documents how to change the default settings used by new projects. Unfortunately, the autoscroll settings are not amongst the ones that can be set there.

A bit more digging shows that the default project is represented by `.IntelliJIdea12\config\options\project.default.xml` and it does not have settings for autoScroll specified. (Out of curiosity, I tried copying in the following in that file :

```
  <component name="ProjectView">
    <navigator currentView="ProjectPane" proportions="" version="1" splitterProportion="0.5">
      <flattenPackages />
      <showMembers />
      <showModules />
      <showLibraryContents />
      <hideEmptyPackages />
      <abbreviatePackageNames />
      <autoscrollToSource ProjectPane="true" />
      <autoscrollFromSource ProjectPane="true" />
      <sortByType />
    </navigator>
  </component>
```

But that was not picked up by new projects.
)

Comment: It's curious these are project-dependent settings, given they really just reflect how a given user prefers to navigate inside the IDE, and have nothing to do with the project itself.

Comment: @RodneyGitzel: Agree, strongly.

Comment: Agreed. It also seems we are not the only ones who think these settings should be IDE level : See [this](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86995) and specailly [**this**](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85255). It would be nice if you could vote for the latter.

Comment: Please go and vote for this feature request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85255

Answer (score 20):

There is now a free IntelliJ plugin to remember Autoscroll to/from Source settings:

Jetbrains repository: [Autoscroll Save Plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7575?pr=)

Instructions to use:

- Download `Autoscroll Save` plugin and restart IntelliJ
- Open an IntelliJ project and set desired autoscroll to and from settings
- Use Ctrl-Alt-Shift END

All IntelliJ projects opened or created in future will now inherit your desired Autoscroll to/from Source settings.

If you have any feedback on the plugin, please click on the author (vikingsteve) on the plugin page and use "Send email" function.

---

**Edit:** I was just at a java conference and spoke to some of the Jetbrains devs from St Petersbourg. After thanking them for developing IntelliJ, I asked them about this, and I understand that since they are really busy with other things they don't have time right now to make this default functionality in IntelliJ.

So, in the meantime, please try out the Autoscroll Save plugin - from everyone I spoke to at the conference, it works for them without problem.

Comment: Oh crap! A plugin for this??? IntelliJ should do it... (thumbs up for the solution though)

Comment: @pihentagy Don't worry, once you've installed the plugin and hit `ctrl-alt-shift END` it will work seamlessly and you won't even notice it running :)