# how to add global configuration to intellij idea

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Whenever I create new project in IntelliJ idea or android studio I had to do some tweaks first to the IDE like for example:-

enable autoscrolling from source
[image]

the problem is I had to this for every project, so I want to know is there a way to make this kind of changes globally.

and disable docked mode in varies windows like this
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable autoscroll to/from source permanently for all new project imports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205860/how-to-enable-autoscroll-to-from-source-permanently-for-all-new-project-imports)

Comment: For the "docked mode", use "Window | Store Current Layout as Default"